# SQL Server 2012 Compatibility with New TLS 1.2 Standards

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, security, connectivity

I'm trying to switch off TLS 1.0 on my SQL Server 2012 server in order to comply with PCI standards.

Initially I had some trouble with the SQL Server service not starting.

I found help for this issue by following answers to a previous question:

[SQL Server compatibility with New TLS Standards](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107820/sql-server-compatibility-with-new-tls-standards)

I'm having mixed results:

I have downloaded SQL Server 2012 Cumulative Update 7 (CU 6 also works) and the SQL Server Service then starts correctly.

I had a problem not being able to sign in to the DB instance through SQL Server Enterprise Manager which was fixed by installing .Net 4.6.

Next problem, client computer running IIS Application is unable to connect to SQL instance because of a 'handshaking SSL error'. I followed advice and installed the latest SNAC native client.

This was difficult to track down and the latest version available as a download from Microsoft was from 2014. I then obtained sqlnclient.msi dated 9/7/2015 revision number {E6CB4138-3D1C-4ADC-95C4-88322B60FC14} from a sub folder generated by the extract of CU 7 - "Path to Extract Folder \1033_enu_lp\x64\setup\x64".

I've updated this version of the Native client on my IIS server (and .Net 4.6) and I'm still unable to connect remotely to the SQL instance. If I enable TLS 1.0 I'm able to connect.

The exact error I'm getting is 'A connection was sucessfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake'.

My diagnosis is I don't have the correct version of SNAC on my machine compatible with TLS 1.2 and the CU 7 as the client and server cannot handshake. However, this sqlnclient.msi was extracted from the CU 7 and I cannot find a more up to date copy.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? What version of the SNAC are you using? Where did you get it?

Thanks