# TLS 1.0 disabled causing errors when requests come from SQL Server to a Webserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, tls-1.2

The issue that I have at the moment is that when I disable TLS 1.0 (due to PCI Compliance) on a web server that hosts our external application, a stored procedure is called from a different server which hosts the database, which creates a HTTP GET Request via sp_OAMethod to call the application on the web server. It returns the following error:

> The connection with the server was terminated abnormally

Using Wireshark we can see that the request that comes from the database server defaults to TLS 1.0 even though we have applied all the cumulative updates so I am now at a loss as to how I can get this resolved.

This is our server setup:

**Webserver:**

- OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Edition
- Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 0 @ 2,40GHz
- RAM: 7.91GB
- System Type: 64-bit OS

**Database Server:**

- OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
- Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 0 @ 2,40GHz
- RAM: 16GB
- System Type: 64-bit OS

**RDBMS**:

```
SQL Server Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5343.0 (X64) 
    May  4 2015 19:11:32 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
```

I have read up on the following articles:

- [SQL Server compatibility with New TLS Standards](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107820/sql-server-compatibility-with-new-tls-standards)
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3135244
- http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/tls-1-2-support-read-first/

but still not able to get anywhere. Any assistance from the community is greatly appreciated.