# Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. DBNETLIB ConnectionOpen SecDoClientHandshake SSL security error

Tags: sql-server, connections, tls-1.2

I'm running all Windows 2016 Servers.  I've got MS SQL 2016 installed on one.  For whatever reason, we cannot connect to the SQL Server unless we enable TLS 1.0 which is obviously not cool.

I found this: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/issues/2783 which talks about how TLS 1.2 should be natively enabled across the board.  I've verified TLS 1.2 is enabled in the registry on all involved servers.  There is another MS doc referred to in the above link that suggests that isn't enough, we may also need to enable ciphers.  So I enabled the RC4 ciphers in the registry on both servers, but still no change.  Unless TLS 1.0 is enabled, no talk.

I can even go onto the SQL Server, and create a .UDL connection test (to itself) and it also fails unless TLS 1.0 is enabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: TLS 1.2 support depends on build version and driver version of the client. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107820/sql-server-compatibility-with-new-tls-standards and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe

Comment: You can change `provider` from `SQLOLEDB` to `MSOLEDBSQL` if that is the case. If possible use newer ones of course. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

The built-in Windows drivers for SQL Server didn't get TLS 1.2 support until Windows Server 2019, see [KB4580390](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/october-20-2020-kb4580390-os-build-17763-1554-preview-ac4799c9-838f-8665-a968-0f19b6cb1049).

On older Windows you'll have to install newer SQL Server [ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) or [OleDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) drivers that support TLS 1.2.

Comment: We actually do have the ODBC driver installed.  What we ended up having to do was to install the SQL Server Native Client and then the magic worked.

Answer (score 1):

We had to install the SQL Server Native Client for SQL 2012 (2016 uses this driver as well) and then I upgraded the version of sqlnci on the SQL Server to the same version, then all was happy.