# SSMS 2016 error "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssms

I am trying to connect a database from SSMS 2016 it gets connected from one machine but other machine with exactly same version SSMS 2016 gives below mentioned issue.

Note: on server only TLS > 1.2 protocols active and it is hosted using Microsoft SQL Server 2012

But if it works on one machine it should be working on other too ( if we are using same version of SSMS 2016).

Not sure what is missing on another machine.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server compatibility with New TLS Standards](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107820/sql-server-compatibility-with-new-tls-standards)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after I disabled SSL 3.0 and kept SSL 2.0 enabled. I had disabled TLS 1.0 and 1.1 and kept only TLS 1.2