# SQL Services Wont Start After Removing TLS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssl

I need to remove TLS 1.0 from one of my SQL servers. When I do so and then reboot the server the SQL services dont start automatically. When I attempt to start them I get an error that it cant be done.
Once I renable TLS 1.0 the SQL services start again after a reboot.

Im running SQL 2012 Developer edition. Version is 11.0.2100.60

Im using IIS crypto to remove TLS.
I keep TLS1.1 and 1.2 on there

Has anyone got a suggestion of what I can do to have the SQL services start when I remove TLS 1.0

Thanks

Comment: Please see if there are any errors recorded in the SQL Server error logs, or Windows Application Event Log.

Answer (score 1):

**You have to patch the sql server instance to a newer version to be able to use TLS 1.2**

Take a look at [TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server)

Either patch at least to [SP2 CU10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3120313/cumulative-update-package-10-for-sql-server-2012-sp2) (preferably a higher CU)
 or [SP3 CU1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3123299).

**When patching to SP3 CU1**

You would still be 9 CU updates behind, the latest CU for SP3 at the time of writing is [SP3 CU10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50733).

So when going this route I would go for SP3 CU10 but preferably choose for SP4

> Note: TLS 1.2 support is also available in 2012 SP4.

**When patching to SP4 (preferred)**

In short, simply patching to [SP4](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4018073/sql-server-2012-service-pack-4-release-information) would be the preferred option, you have to remember that there is a [hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4091266/on-demand-hotfix-update-package-for-sql-server-2012-sp4) out for this Service Pack.

More questions and answers on disabling tls 1.0 and the sql server service not being able to start 
[here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93127/sql-server-service-won-t-start-after-disabling-tls-1-0-and-ssl-3-0) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107820/sql-server-compatibility-with-new-tls-standards)